# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Hello I have this kind of problem.. I tried to install kubuntu plasma desktop but somehow it failed during installation ..now I can't use apt-get can you guys help me somehow? thank you.

```
>  
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 haveged : Depends: libhavege1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and run :

```
sudo apt-get -f install && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install
```

if result

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

run  this :

```
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

and try reinstall package

Comment: when I try third command I get this http://pastebin.com/ybhsD9yE   and when I try sudo apt-get autoremove I get this http://pastebin.com/R9mgScYq

Comment: run : sudo dpkg -r  account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive && 
sudo apt-get -f install. i think there is wrong with kubuntu dependecies and you need to  force remove those package.

Comment: Unmet dependencies doesn't let you install anything because there is a glitch created in sources.list file

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late to respond but in current versions of `apt`, unmet dependencies can be fixed with

```
apt install --fix-broken
```

Took the answer from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592244/478125) post.